# Is there a faster way to find the order of a COLUMN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My SQL Server table looks like this

```
ID   a_Toyota   a_Mazda   a_Nissan   a_Kia   a_Honda   a_Subaru     SoldCar   CarOrder
1    8000       7000      6200       8500    6500      7000         Mazda     NULL
2    4000       5000      4500       3500    3500      5000         Mazda     NULL
3    5400       5000      4500       5500    5500      4600         Mazda     NULL
4    5600       6300      7500       8200    6500      7300         Mazda     NULL
5    8500       7400      7400       6500    9500      9000         Mazda     NULL
6    9900       8000      9900       7300    8100      8000         Mazda     NULL
```

I want to Update CarOrder field, so it has the order of price of the sold car compare to other car prices.

So for ID 1 car prices ordered as **a_Kia (8500)** is **1st** and **a_Toyota (8000)** is **2nd**  and **a_Mazda & a_Subaru (7000)** are **3rd** and **a_Honda (6500)** is **5th** and **a_Nissan (6200)** is **6th**
and the sold car was Mazda which is 3rd so the table should be as follow

```
ID   a_Toyota   a_Mazda   a_Nissan   a_Kia   a_Honda   a_Subaru     SoldCar   CarOrder
1    8000       7000      6200       8500    6500      7000         Mazda     3
2    4000       5000      4500       3500    3500      5000         Subaru    1
3    5400       5000      4500       5500    5500      4600         Toyota    3
4    5600       6300      7500       8200    6500      7300         Honda     4
5    8500       7400      7400       6500    9500      9000         Honda     1
6    9900       8000      9900       7300    8100      8000         Honda     3
```

I can find the order with a large CASE statement

```
UPDATE mytable
SET CarOrder =
CASE WHEN SoldCar = 'Toyota' AND a_Toyota>=a_Mazda AND a_Toyota>=a_Nissan AND ... AND a_Toyota>=a_Subaru THEN 1 
CASE WHEN SoldCar = 'Toyota' AND a_Toyota<a_Mazda AND a_Toyota>=a_Nissan AND ... AND a_Toyota>=a_Subaru THEN 2 
CASE WHEN SoldCar = 'Toyota' AND a_Toyota>=a_Mazda AND a_Toyota<a_Nissan AND ... AND a_Toyota>=a_Subaru THEN 2 
.
.
.
CASE WHEN SoldCar = 'Toyota' AND a_Toyota>=a_Mazda AND a_Toyota>=a_Nissan AND ... AND a_Toyota<a_Subaru THEN 2 
.
.
.
CASE WHEN SoldCar = 'Toyota' AND a_Toyota<a_Mazda AND a_Toyota<a_Nissan AND ... AND a_Toyota>=a_Subaru THEN 3
..
..
..
```

but this is going to be a huge case statement.

I wonder if someone has an easier way to do that?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for the calarification

Comment: Seems like you have a denormalised design, if I am honest. I suspect you should have 2 tables, not 1, and many rows per `ID` (1 for each make).

Comment: I don't quite follow your logic, but you might be able to use the `row_number()` window function to do your ordering.

Comment: Your table is seriously denormalized. I suggest you sort out the design before going further otherwise you are going to tie yourself in knots on every query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more method based on XQuery.

For the row where ID=2, there is a tie between Subary and Mazda. They both have value of 5000.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    a_Toyota INT,
    a_Mazda INT,
    a_Nissan INT,
    a_Kia INT,
    a_Honda INT,
    a_Subaru INT,
    SoldCar VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    a_Toyota,
    a_Mazda,
    a_Nissan,
    a_Kia,
    a_Honda,
    a_Subaru,
    SoldCar
) VALUES
(8000, 7000, 6200, 8500, 6500, 7000, 'Mazda'),
(4000, 5000, 4500, 3500, 3500, 5000, 'Subaru'),
(5400, 5000, 4500, 5500, 5500, 4600, 'Toyota'),
(5600, 6300, 7500, 8200, 6500, 7300, 'Honda'),
(8500, 7400, 7400, 6500, 9500, 9000, 'Honda'),
(9900, 8000, 9900, 7300, 8100, 8000, 'Honda');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*, CarOrder 
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT a_Toyota, a_Mazda, a_Nissan,
    a_Kia, a_Honda, a_Subaru, SoldCar
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.query('<root>
{
for $r in /root/*
order by data($r) descending
return <r>
        <make>{local-name($r)}</make>
        <salePrice>{data($r)}</salePrice>
    </r>
}
</root>').query('
    let $soldcar := sql:column("SoldCar")
    for $r in /root/r[contains((make/text())[1], $soldcar)]
    let $pos := count(root/*[. << $r])
    return $pos').value('.','INT')
) AS t2(CarOrder);
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------+---------+----------+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| ID | a_Toyota | a_Mazda | a_Nissan | a_Kia | a_Honda | a_Subaru | SoldCar | CarOrder |
+----+----------+---------+----------+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|  1 |     8000 |    7000 |     6200 |  8500 |    6500 |     7000 | Mazda   |        3 |
|  2 |     4000 |    5000 |     4500 |  3500 |    3500 |     5000 | Subaru  |        2 |
|  3 |     5400 |    5000 |     4500 |  5500 |    5500 |     4600 | Toyota  |        3 |
|  4 |     5600 |    6300 |     7500 |  8200 |    6500 |     7300 | Honda   |        4 |
|  5 |     8500 |    7400 |     7400 |  6500 |    9500 |     9000 | Honda   |        1 |
|  6 |     9900 |    8000 |     9900 |  7300 |    8100 |     8000 | Honda   |        3 |
+----+----------+---------+----------+-------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option where you don't have to enumerate the columns to unpivot.

This also assumes the column names have the prefix of `a_`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ddac9146c0823519a512b9bcba5afacb)**

```
with cte as (
Select * 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select *
                     ,rn=row_number() over (order by convert(decimal(12,2),value) desc)
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper  )) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('ID','SoldCar','CarOrder')
             ) B
 Where [key] ='a_'+SoldCar  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
)
Update cte set CarOrder = RN
```

**The Updated Table**

[image]

Comment: you can right click in the corner of the resultset and copy with header. Later, convert into github flavoured mark up table here: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ and paste it here. We can avoid the use of images.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table structure similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb..cars
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    a_Toyota INT NOT NULL,
    a_Mazda INT NOT NULL,
    a_Nissan INT NOT NULL,
    a_Kia INT NOT NULL,
    a_Honda INT NOT NULL,
    a_Subaru INT NOT NULL,
    SoldCar VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CarOrder INT NULL
);
```

One approach would be to leverage an [APPLY operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply). Something like the following should give you a resultset from a table structure like above, assuming the use of CROSS APPLY and a non-dense [RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (vs a [DENSE RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) along with descending order for determining your ordering:

```
SELECT  c.ID, c.SoldCar, o.ord AS CarOrder
FROM    tempdb..cars c
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  t.ord
        FROM    (
                SELECT  r.car, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.qty DESC) AS ord
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  c.a_Toyota AS qty, 'Toyota' AS car
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  c.a_Mazda AS qty, 'Mazda' AS car
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  c.a_Nissan AS qty, 'Nissan' AS car
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  c.a_Kia AS qty, 'Kia' AS car
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  c.a_Honda AS qty, 'Honda' AS car
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  c.a_Subaru AS qty, 'Subaru' AS car
                        ) r
                ) t
        WHERE   t.car = c.SoldCar
        ) o
```

Answer (score 0):

The table structure needs pivoting into something it should be from the outset that would facilitate easily determining the correct order and catering for any number of brands.

You can do this using a cross-apply and row_number to match each value with its ordinal position, using an updatable CTE to update the base table.

```
with cars as (
    select * from t
    cross apply (
        select case soldcar
          when 'Toyota' then a_Toyota
          when 'Mazda'  then a_Mazda
          when 'Nissan' then a_Nissan
          when 'Honda'  then a_Honda
          when 'Subaru' then a_Subaru
        end
    )s(SoldValue)
    cross apply (
      select rank() over (order by v desc) co, v
      from (values(a_toyota),(a_mazda),(a_nissan),(a_kia),(a_honda),(a_subaru))v(v)
    )c
    where SoldValue=v
)
update cars set carOrder=co
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfc7418ad2934f0875cdc8f985bf0a9b)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. You just append rank of the current SoldCar among the first 6 columns to the corresponding record. It is complicated to do this in SQL. The language needs the cross apply assisted by XQuery, or by OpenJson and the window function. The statement is lengthy and hard to read. An alternative is to export data out of database and handle it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easier to be integrated into a Java program and generate much simpler code. It gets this done with only three lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =MSSQL.query("select a_Toyota,a_Mazda,a_Nissan,a_Kia,a_Honda,a_Subaru,'a_'+SoldCar as SoldCar from cars") |
| 2 | =A1.fname().m(:-2) |
| 3 | =A1.derive([${A2.concat@c()}].ranks@z()(A2.pselect(~==A1.~.#7)):CarOrder) |